# UINavigationController changing view problem

Tags: iphone

I have a problem for changing the displayed view.

My app contains 2 views controllers. One audio player and 1 about.
The Audio view controller is never released and the second is released when the audio
viewController push.

My app also has an AppDelegate object which is shared by all UIViewControllers.
AppDelegate Class contains the UINavigationController instance which is responsible to display 
the right view.

So for pushing the about vire I use this code :

```
[appDelegate.navigationController pushViewController:initialLoadingViewController animated:NO];
```

It works well except for the second time I got an error saying that the same view controller 
is already present.

I also tried popToViewController : the correct view appears but all buttons seems disabled then my app crashes.

So my question is : what is the best way to change the current viewController ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Thierry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navigation-controller maintains a stack of view-controllers. I assume the audio-view should be the first one to be seen. This is the root view-controller. When the user requests it (or some other event), you push the about view-controller on the navigation-controllers view-stack (`pushViewController:animated:`).

To return to the audio-view, you just pop the about view-controller with `popViewControllerAnimated:`. After that, the about view-controller can be released. You need to allocate it again (i.e. reload it from a .nib file), if you need it again.

[Apple's introduction to view controllers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing more code, but it sounds like you're trying to pop to a view controller which you've released. When you push another view controller onto the stack, don't release anything and see if that fixes the crash....

BTW, appDelegate.navigationController looks suspicious - try using self.navigationController.